How can I make my audio loop after it finishes?
I am trying to make an audio file (jump.mp3) loop using Howler.js. However, the audio only plays once and does not repeat after it ends.
What I expected:

The audio should loop (repeat automatically) once it reaches the end.

What happens:

The audio plays only once and does not repeat after it ends.

How can I modify my code to ensure the audio repeats automatically after it finishes playing?
Here is a full Stackblitz Demo.
Here is my code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Audio Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="repeatAudio()">Repeat Audio</button>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/howler@2.2.3/dist/howler.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      class AudioManager {
        static sounds = {};
        static volume = 1;

        static load(audioFile) {
          if (!this.sounds[audioFile]) {
            this.sounds[audioFile] = new Howl({
              src: [audioFile],
              volume: this.volume,
              preload: true,
              onend: () => {},
            });
          }
        }

        static play(audioFile) {
          if (!this.sounds[audioFile]) {
            this.load(audioFile);
          }
          this.sounds[audioFile].play();
        }

        static replay(audioFile) {
          if (!this.sounds[audioFile]) {
            this.load(audioFile);
          }
          const sound = this.sounds[audioFile];
          sound.stop();
          sound.play();
        }
      }

      function repeatAudio() {
        AudioManager.replay('jump.mp3');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>


Out of curiosity, why are you using Howler?  I haven't seen a good use case for it in at least a decade.

@Brad what should I use instead?

That depends on why you're using Howler, which I asked.  For what we see here, you can just use a normal audio element.  const audio = new Audio(url)

@Brad Howler has for example settings to loop a audio and other functions. Thats, why I 'm using it.

audio.loop = true

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

You just need to add loop: true into the Howl settings.
this.sounds[audioFile] = new Howl({
              src: [audioFile],
              volume: this.volume,
              preload: true,
              onend: () => {},
              loop: true,
            });

